# Массовое добавление данных в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток.

```
<?
// if (строк > 0) {цикл;} else {переходим на страницу "X" ;}

// описание цикла
// 1. получаем данные 1й строки $a=***; $b=***; $c=***;
// 2. ест-но, сразу же записываем в БД
// 3. строка = строка + 1
?>
```

Есть огромный файл (не суть важно, какого формата (п.1)) . Хочется засунуть его содержимое в mysql таблицу.  Естественно построчным перебором. Подскажите, как написать?

P.S. Алгоритм п.1. и п.2. - пусть останутся за мной, интересует все остальное. Ну и что бы сервер не выдал что ни будь в духе: превышено время ожидания.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала было бы неплохо убрать 30-секундный(по умолчанию) лимит выполнения скрипта, раз файл и правда такой большой:

```
   set_time_limit(0);
```

А вообще, решение данной задачи специфично для определенных ситуаций. Так, например, если вам надо тупо запихнуть файл в базу( чтобы потом прочитать содержимое ), то можно использовать поля типа BLOB

Answer (score 2):

Самые простые варианты:

1. Попробовать использовать [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)
2. Вставлять одним инсертом сразу много записей

Comment: Угу. А дополнительную документацию и примеры искать по фразе "bulk load mysql"

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте делать редиректом.

Т.е. GET'ом передавать скрипту переменную, содержащую номер строки, с которой надо начать.